# Running a R console in RInside

Tags: r, readline, rinside

Is it possible to run something similar to a Linux R console (which uses GNU Readline) from within a C++ program using RInside? The best option would be, if such a console would have all the nice features like the autocomplete.

**The background:**
I have a big solver, which has a RInside-based plugin for running small chunks of R code during a simulation. It would be nice if the user would be able to switch it to "interactive" mode and check things out as they go.

**Notice:**
1. I cannot just run R as a separate program, as I need it to see my objects and pointers from the main code. 2. I know about callbacks in RInside, but they do not provide any console-like capabilities.

**Code:** I doubt it will help, but here is my code now: https://github.com/llaniewski/TCLB/blob/RInside/src/Handlers/cbRunR.cpp.Rt

Comment: The embedded R session used by RInside, taking advantage of the existing embedding API, *is* the console.  If I understand you correctly, you basically want a second parallel instance. That feature simply does not exist, and that has nothing to do with Rcpp or RInside but with how R is designed and built.

Comment: Sorry, if the question is unclear. I would want to do more or less the same thing as in rinside_callback0.cpp example. But with GNU Readline-supported autocomplete, like in the normal R console. I was wondering if one can reuse the R Console code inside of RInside integration, or directly from R DLL. I see that libreadline is linked by libRInside, but I do not know how to run a R Console-like input routine. (I'll try to update the question)

Comment: Ok, I just found this: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/blob/master/src/RInside.cpp#L149 - This explains a lot.

Comment: You are still confused.  RInside embeds the R interpreter. As you would on the command-line, but sends it instruction line by line -- look up REPL if unclear.  This is merely a startup option _just like R would have_ and has nothing to do with readline linking.

Comment: When you embed R you get the libreadline interface automatically, that why I was surprised that it is not working with RInside. The reason is that even for 'interactive=true' in RInside constructor, there is still a '--no-readline' passed to the Rf_initEmbeddedR. I created a relevant pull request in the RInside github repo.

Comment: Yes, let's continue over there.  I already followed up too.